# How to do PoseBone.children?

Tags: scripting, armature

I got an armature, with bones connected, so everything set up just fine. I want to get a bone's children through the `.pose`.

Like:

```
v = objects["armature"]
a = v.pose.bones[0] #got the root bone
```

Then I want to go through the children recursively. Only problem is that `a` is a PoseBone and has only `.child` property.

Only way I found to get all the children is like `a.bone.children` then get all of their `.name` and find them in `v`. That is "fine"...

**My question** to the more experienced bpy fans is that if there is a better way to get this set of bones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `children` attribute is a convenience property, That is to say - Blender doesn't store a list of children for each bone, This attribute has just been added to some types since its such a common task.

Objects have this, but as you have noticed, not pose bones.

This can be [monkey-patched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) in with:

```
import bpy

def pose_bone_children(self):
    obj = self.id_data
    pbones = obj.pose.bones
    self_bone = self.bone
    return tuple(pbones[bone.name] for bone in obj.data.bones
                 if bone.parent == self_bone)

# Add the property to the class at runtime
bpy.types.PoseBone.children = property(pose_bone_children)
```

Note that this will be included in 2.69, Committed [r60407](https://projects.blender.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=bf-blender&revision=60407)